# how to set duration or delay for transform translate3d I'm trying to carousel vertical

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to do carousel vertical. I did it but slides move very fast I want to slow down transition can any one help me please ? 
I'm using bootstrap 4.1

```css
.vert .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
.vert .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.vert .carousel-item-next,
.vert .active.carousel-item-right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 100% 0);
}

.vert .carousel-item-prev,
.vert .active.carousel-item-left {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0,-100%, 0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel vert slide vertical" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="900">
     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
         <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
         <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
         <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
     </ol>
     <div class="carousel-inner">
         <div class="carousel-item active">
             <img class="d-block mx-auto img-fluid" src="image/4.png" alt="First slide">
         </div>
         <div class="carousel-item">
             <img class="d-block mx-auto img-fluid" src="image/3.png" alt="Second slide">
         </div>
         <div class="carousel-item">
             <img class="d-block mx-auto img-fluid" src="image/2.png" alt="Third slide">
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Try my code posted below. I have updated only css. you can change time duration using " transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left; " .

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If one of the answers did help than check it as the answer. If not than update the question and add extra information

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply set the interval in JS as in the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#via-javascript

> interval  number  5000    The amount of time to delay between automatically cycling an item. If false, carousel will not automatically cycle.

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 5000 // Set the interval in JS
})
```

```css
.vert .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
.vert .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.vert .carousel-item-next,
.vert .active.carousel-item-right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 100% 0);
}

.vert .carousel-item-prev,
.vert .active.carousel-item-left {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0,-100%, 0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel vert slide vertical" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="900">
     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
         <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
         <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
         <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
     </ol>
     <div class="carousel-inner">
         <div class="carousel-item active">
             <img class="d-block mx-auto img-fluid" src="image/4.png" alt="First slide">
         </div>
         <div class="carousel-item">
             <img class="d-block mx-auto img-fluid" src="image/3.png" alt="Second slide">
         </div>
         <div class="carousel-item">
             <img class="d-block mx-auto img-fluid" src="image/2.png" alt="Third slide">
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .vert .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
    .vert .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                position: relative;
        /* new styles */
        display: none;
        -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
        -moz-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
        -o-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
        transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
    }
    
    .vert .carousel-item-next,
    .vert .active.carousel-item-right {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
                transform: translate3d(0, 100% 0);
    }
    
    .vert .carousel-item-prev,
    .vert .active.carousel-item-left {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0,-100%, 0);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel vert slide vertical" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="900">
           <ol class="carousel-indicators">
               <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
               <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
               <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
           </ol>
           <div class="carousel-inner">
               <div class="carousel-item active">
                   <img class="d-block mx-auto img-fluid" src="image/4.png" alt="First slide">
               </div>
               <div class="carousel-item">
                   <img class="d-block mx-auto img-fluid" src="image/3.png" alt="Second slide">
               </div>
               <div class="carousel-item">
                   <img class="d-block mx-auto img-fluid" src="image/2.png" alt="Third slide">
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/aoxy9buc/5/

I have updated only CSS. Try this.Let me know if you have any problem.
Thanks.